# Is there a way you can get two Scanner input(integers) without going to the next line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on grade calculator and I intend to get marks scored and the maximum marks. I need to use Scanner such that, if the number of tests taken is two it will prompt the user to enter the score and the maximum score on the same line. After that it goes to the next line and asks the user to input score as well as maximum score. It thereafter finds the sum of score and the sum of maximum score separately.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can queue-up integer values on the same line by using `scan.nextInt()`. It will wait until it reads two integers, either separated by spaces or new-lines.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter grade(s): ");
        int score = scan.nextInt();
        int maxScore = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Score: %d, Max: %d%n", score, maxScore);

        scan.close(); // Close scanner.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much@Mr. Polywhirl for the quick response. However, I after entering the score, the cursor goes to the next line. I need the output to be exactly as shown in the attached screenshot.

Comment: @DavidKyosi The cursor only goes to the next line if you press enter. Don't. Type number, then space, then next number, and *then* enter.

Comment: @DavidKyosi Can you post the code you have got so far?

Comment: Thanks so much @Mr Polywhirl and Andreas. Problem solved. The code was correct only that I was pressing enter before entering the next input. Lol, you saved me guys.